# create Trigger mutating error

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need to create a trigger that whenever you make an update to a column in a table he'll verify that meets the requirements.
I create this trigger:

```
       create or replace trigger trg_utente_activo 
    before update of idestado on utente
    for each row
    when (new.idestado = 3)
    declare
      ex_analises_geneticas EXCEPTION;
      flag boolean :=true;
    /*Vai buscar todas as analises obrigatorias*/
    cursor AnObri is
        select an_ob.codAnalise
        from AnalisesObrigatorias an_ob,analise a, tipoanalise ta
        where an_ob.codanalise like a.codanalise
        and a.idtipoanalise like ta.idtipoanalise 
        and ta.TipoAnaliseEnum like 3
        order by an_ob.codAnalise;
        AnalisesObrig AnObri%rowtype;
        /*Vai buscar todas as analises obrigatorias que o utente fez*/
    cursor AnObriUtent is
        select distinct req_a.codanalise
        from analise a,utente u,requisicao req,requisicao_analise req_a,analisesobrigatorias an_obr,tipoanalise ta
        where :new.idutente=req.idutente 
          and :new.idutente=u.idutente
          and an_obr.tipoutente=u.tipoutente
          and an_obr.codAnalise=a.codAnalise
          and req_a.codanalise=a.codanalise
          and ta.idtipoanalise=a.idtipoanalise 
          and ta.TipoAnaliseEnum = 3
          order by (req_a.codanalise);
        Analise AnObriUtent%ROWTYPE;

    begin 
    open AnObri;
    open AnObriUtent;
    loop
        fetch AnObri into AnalisesObrig;
        fetch AnObriUtent into Analise;
        if (Analise.codAnalise not like AnalisesObrig.codAnalise) then
           dbms_output.put_line(AnalisesObrig.codAnalise);
           flag:=false;
           dbms_output.put_line('flag ' || sys.diutil.bool_to_int(flag));
        else 
           dbms_output.put_line(AnalisesObrig.codAnalise || '-' || Analise.codAnalise);
           dbms_output.put_line('flag ' ||  sys.diutil.bool_to_int(flag));
        end if;   
    end loop;
      if (flag = true) then 
        update utente ut
          set ut.idestado = :new.idestado
        where idutente = idutente;
      else 
          raise ex_analises_geneticas;
      end if;
      close AnObriUtent;
      close AnObri;
      EXCEPTION 
       WHEN ex_analises_geneticas THEN 
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'O utente não realizou todas as analises geneticas'); 
    END;
```

/

Update Query:

```
update utente
  set idestado=3
where idutente=1;
```

But give me this error message:

```
ORA-06512: na "BD1415_DK9.TRG_UTENTE_ACTIVO", linha 12
ORA-06512: na "BD1415_DK9.TRG_UTENTE_ACTIVO", linha 27
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do trigger 'BD1415_DK9.TRG_UTENTE_ACTIVO'
(ORA-04088: error during execution)
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
```

I try with this **pragma autonomous_transaction** but give me error
can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger is on update of `utente.idestado`, but it CONTAINS an update to that same column, meaning that, if the validation is passed, you'll go into an infinite loop i.e. your trigger will do an update which will fire the trigger which will do an update which will fire the trigger etc etc etc...

Are you sure you didn't just need to do this:

```
create or replace trigger trg_utente_activo before update of idestado on utente

for each row
  when (new.idestado = 3)
    declare
      ex_analises_geneticas EXCEPTION;
      flag boolean :=true;

      /*Vai buscar todas as analises obrigatorias*/
      cursor AnObri is
        select an_ob.codAnalise
        from AnalisesObrigatorias an_ob,analise a, tipoanalise ta
        where an_ob.codanalise like a.codanalise
        and a.idtipoanalise like ta.idtipoanalise 
        and ta.TipoAnaliseEnum like 3
        order by an_ob.codAnalise;

      AnalisesObrig AnObri%rowtype;

      /*Vai buscar todas as analises obrigatorias que o utente fez*/
      cursor AnObriUtent is
        select distinct req_a.codanalise
        from analise a,utente u,requisicao req,requisicao_analise req_a,analisesobrigatorias an_obr,tipoanalise ta
        where :new.idutente=req.idutente 
        and :new.idutente=u.idutente
        and an_obr.tipoutente=u.tipoutente
        and an_obr.codAnalise=a.codAnalise
        and req_a.codanalise=a.codanalise
        and ta.idtipoanalise=a.idtipoanalise 
        and ta.TipoAnaliseEnum = 3
        order by (req_a.codanalise);

      Analise AnObriUtent%ROWTYPE;

      begin 
        open AnObri;
          open AnObriUtent;
            loop
              fetch AnObri into AnalisesObrig;
              fetch AnObriUtent into Analise;
                if (Analise.codAnalise not like AnalisesObrig.codAnalise) then
                  dbms_output.put_line(AnalisesObrig.codAnalise);
                  flag:=false;
                  dbms_output.put_line('flag ' || sys.diutil.bool_to_int(flag));
                else 
                  dbms_output.put_line(AnalisesObrig.codAnalise || '-' || Analise.codAnalise);
                  dbms_output.put_line('flag ' ||  sys.diutil.bool_to_int(flag));
                end if;   
            end loop;

            if (flag = false) then 
              raise ex_analises_geneticas;
            end if;
          close AnObriUtent;
        close AnObri;
      EXCEPTION 
        WHEN ex_analises_geneticas THEN 
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'O utente não realizou todas as analises geneticas'); 
      END;
/
```

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-04091: tabela BD1415_DK9.UTENTE está em mutação, trigger não a pode ler ou modificar
ORA-06512: na "BD1415_DK9.TRG_UTENTE_ACTIVO", linha 18
ORA-06512: na "BD1415_DK9.TRG_UTENTE_ACTIVO", linha 33
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do trigger 'BD1415_DK9.TRG_UTENTE_ACTIVO'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

Comment: Thats odd.. the only other thing I can suggest is that your `AnObriUtent` is causing the problem because you're selecting from the table you're in the process of updating. I'll update the answer to remove this as well as I don't think you need it..

Comment: i need because i need to check if values on the cursor AnObri are on the cursor AnObriUtent if a field does not exist then it will not stop updating. you update the answer you gave me?